# Prove there exists $y_0 \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $ P(X-Y \in B) \geq P(X-y_0 \in B)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I wish to prove that for  $ B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) $ and $X$ and $Y$ denote independent random variables there exists $y_0 \in \mathbb{R} $ such that
$$
P(X-Y \in B) \geq P(X-y_0 \in B).
$$
**My attempt:**
Consider the measurable function $m:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}:(x,y) \mapsto x-y$. Then
\begin{align*}
P(X-Y \in B) &= E[1_B(m(X,Y))] \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} 1_B(m) d(P_X \otimes P_Y) \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} 1_B(m(x,y)) P_X(dx)P_Y(dy) \\
&\geq \int_\mathbb{R} \inf_{z \in \mathbb{R}} P(X-z \in B) P_Y(dy) \\
&= \inf_{z \in \mathbb{R}} P(X-z \in B).
\end{align*}
The infimum exists but how can I pick $y_0$? If I pick $y_0$ as an element giving the infimum, I need to know such an element exists. Can I pick it in a different way?

Answer (score 3):

Following your calculations, we have :
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X-Y \in B) &= \int_{\mathbb R} \left( \int_{\mathbb R} 1_B(x-y)P_X(\text dx) \right) P_Y(\text dy) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} \mathbb P(X-y\in B) P_Y(\text dy) \\
&\geq \int_{\mathbb R} \inf_{z \in \mathbb R} \mathbb P(X-z\in B) P_Y(\text dy) \\
& = \inf_{z \in \mathbb R} \mathbb P(X-z\in B)
\end{align}

Now, if there is equality, by positivity of the Lebesgue integral, we have :
$$\mathbb P(X-y\in B) = \inf_{z \in \mathbb R} \mathbb P(X-z\in B) \qquad P_Y(\text{d} y)-\text{almost surely}$$
in which case we are done.

In the other case, by definition of the $\inf$, there is $y\in \mathbb R$ such that :
$$\mathbb P(X-Y \in B) \geq \mathbb P(X-y\in B)$$

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the equality case, I'm note sure I follow. How do we pick a $y_0$ in this case?

Comment: For a probability measure $\text d\mu$, measurable function $f$ and constant, if we have $f\geq c$ and $\int f \text d\mu = c$, then $f(x) = c$ almost surely. There must then be some $x$ such that $f(x)= c$.